# Write big OpenCv Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, memory, 64-bit

I'm trying to write big float matrix in OpenCV Mat format to binary file.I'm on virtual box with Linux x64.

And I have crush around counter 536000000, so it seems I have overflow of int around "suspicious line" in p+i*4? (by the way, assert doesn't detect this case, why?).

So when I change "int i" to "int64 i", everything seems ok, but I'm not sure if it is safe to add more then 2^32 to char* pointer?

Also, what is the max size of OpenCV matrix?

```
    bool WriteFloatMat(string path, const Mat &img)
    {
        ofstream fs(path, ios::binary);

        fs.write( (char*)&(img.cols), 4);
        fs.write( (char*)&(img.rows), 4);

        int64 sz_ = img.cols*img.rows;//
        assert(sz_ < numeric_limits<int>::max());//

        int sz = img.cols*img.rows;
        cout << sz << endl;
        int64 counter=0;
        int64 maxVal= numeric_limits<int>::max();
        char* p= image.ptr<char>();
        for(int i=0; i<sz; ++i)
        {
            assert(i*4 < numeric_limits<int>::max());//suspicious line
            fs.write( p+i*4, 4);
            ++counter;
            if(counter%1000000==0)
                cout << counter << endl;
            if(counter>maxVal)
                cout << "Out of limits!" << endl;
        }

        return true;
    }


void TestIO()
{
    //max matrix dimensions?
    int rows= 1000*1000*10;
    int cols= 100;
    Mat mat(rows,cols,CV_32FC1);
    mat=mat+7;

    double t = (double)getTickCount();
    WriteFloatMat("/media/dummy.big", mat);
    t = ((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Times passed in seconds: " << t << endl;
}
```

**Update:**
I understand why `assert(i*4 < numeric_limits<int>::max());` doesn't work, because i*4 overflow and <0 so `assert(i*4 >=0 );` works.

Comment: why are you writing one value at the time? can't you just write the whole data matrix at once? Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31584182/5008845) for an example

Comment: @Miki Is there any limitation of `ofs.write` , because I want to write big files > 4Gb?

Comment: You should be ok with file > 4Gb.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV does not have internal limits on the size of an image, which it is really treating as a block of memory. So the limitations will be with the C++ system you are using.

For what it is worth, I have found the [numeric_cast<>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html) functionality in the boost numeric library to be very helpful catching conversion errors like you encountered with `assert(i*4 < numeric_limits<int>::max())`. (Of course, that problem was subtle, so it may not have helped there either.)